# How does $\frac{21x^3}{x^{1/2}}$ simplify to $21x^{5/2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Need clarification on why the fraction $\frac{21x^3}{x^{1/2}}$  simplifies to $21x^{5/2}$. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please use mathjax:https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the properties of exponents , a$^b$ .a$^c$ = a$^{b+c}$ and $\frac{1}{a^b}$= a$^{-b}$

Your question beomces $\frac{21x^3}{x^{1/2}}$ = 21.x$^{3-{1/2}}$ = 21x$^{\frac{6-1}{2}}$ = 21x$^{5/2}$.

Answer (score 0):

When you divide $x^3$ by $x^{1/2}$ you need to subtract the exponents.

Note that $$ 3-1/2 = 6/2 - 1/2 = 5/2$$

That is why you have $x^{5/2}$ in your answer.

Comment: It is $5/3$ in the answer

Comment: I'm guessing that's a typo